# List of URLs to be whitelisted

Tags: node.js, botframework

I need to deploy my Bot behind a firewall.
However, from the documentation, I was unable to find a list of URLs that need to be whitelisted.

I have read through the code and found this

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/69176d237bc9ba7a5b506d55389a5c76f099e411/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts

Not sure if this list is sufficient and need advice on this.

Comment: If you are using open_url type, your url must be white listed. What channel do you use ?

Comment: Not sure why i'm getting downvoted for a valid question. I'm using directline

Answer (score 1):

It would be almost impossible for someone to provide you with a comprehensive list of all endpoints.  Your best solution is to inspect network traffic through something like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and see what traffic will need to be whitelisted.